# CSS Property "overflow-y: auto" causing very unexpected results

Tags: html, css

The following code is part of a custom 404 page I am planning on using on a website of mine. However there is a major problem when I add the line of code `overflow-y: auto;`

The code below has the output which I expected it to. However when it the code inside the div reaches more than `75vh` the overflow is not visible.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.main {
 min-height: 100vh;
 font-size: 1em;
 overflow-Y: hidden;
}

.center {
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 left: 50%;
}

.wrap {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 left: -50%;
}

.load_extra {
 display: block;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 11;
 bottom: 15px;
}

.prep {
 align: center;
 background: #00eaff;
 outline: none;

 padding: 8px;

 color: white;

 border-color: white;
 border-style: dotted;
 border-width: 3px;
 border-radius:50%;
 font-size: 1.375em;
}

.extra {
 display: block;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 10px;
 max-height: 75vh;
 width: 80vw;
 z-index: 10;
}

pre {
 font-family: monospace, monospace;
 font-size: 0.85em;
 display: block;
 overflow-y: auto;
 word-break: break-all;
 white-space:normal;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 0 0 10px;
 line-height: 1.42857143;
 color: #333;
 word-break: break-all;
 word-wrap: break-word;
 background-color: #f5f5f5;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 4px;
 max-height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<body class="main">
 <div class="center load_extra">
  <div class="wrap">
   <button id="extra" class="prep">Button</button>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div id="infoCont" class="center extra">
  <div class="wrap">
   <h1>Extra Information</h1>
   <pre>Some URL</pre>
   <p>The requested URL shown above could not be found on the server</p>
   <hr>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

In order to fix this problem I added the line `overflow-y: auto;` in `.extra` class. This is what caused a problem. When you run the code below half of the output is "missing". I am unsure of why this is occuring.

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.main {
 min-height: 100vh;
 font-size: 1em;
 overflow-Y: hidden;
}

.center {
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 left: 50%;
}

.wrap {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 left: -50%;
}

.load_extra {
 display: block;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 11;
 bottom: 15px;
}

.prep {
 align: center;
 background: #00eaff;
 outline: none;

 padding: 8px;

 color: white;

 border-color: white;
 border-style: dotted;
 border-width: 3px;
 border-radius:50%;
 font-size: 1.375em;
}

.extra {
 display: block;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 10px;
 max-height: 75vh;
 width: 80vw;
 z-index: 10;
 overflow-y: auto;
}

pre {
 font-family: monospace, monospace;
 font-size: 0.85em;
 display: block;
 overflow-y: auto;
 word-break: break-all;
 white-space:normal;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 0 0 10px;
 line-height: 1.42857143;
 color: #333;
 word-break: break-all;
 word-wrap: break-word;
 background-color: #f5f5f5;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 4px;
 max-height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<body class="main">
 <div class="center load_extra">
  <div class="wrap">
   <button id="extra" class="prep">Button</button>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div id="infoCont" class="center extra">
  <div class="wrap">
   <h1>Extra Information</h1>
   <pre>Some URL</pre>
   <p>The requested URL shown above could not be found on the server</p>
   <hr>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

I would appreciate any help in fixing this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Half of the output goes "missing" due to the `left` positions defined in `center` and `wrap` classes.

`center` class will position your container starting from 50% and then, the inner container (`wrap`) gets repositioned again with -50%. Since the overflow is applied on the parent div, half of the content is no longer visible.

One solution might be to move `overflow-y: auto;` to `wrap` class.

Another is to choose another way to center `infoCont` div.

```
<div id="infoCont" class="extra">
   <h1>Extra Information</h1>
   <pre>Some URL</pre>
   <p>The requested URL shown above could not be found on the server</p>
   <hr>
</div>

.extra {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10px;
    max-height: 75vh;
    width: 80vw;
    z-index: 10;
    overflow-y: auto;
    margin: 0 auto; /* set margin to auto */
    left: 0;        /* set also left and right because position is fixed */
    right: 0;
}
```

See working [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OXEXLR).